# Type manipulation: Map optional nullable type to another optional nullable type with recursion

Tags: typescript

Need help to write concise form for below code with recursion

What I'm looking for is
if given type is `T1 | null | undefined`
I would like to convert it to `T2 | null | undefined`

`T1` can be optional or nullable, i.e we can have `T1 | null` or `T1 | undefined`

```js
type DateJson = {
  __type: 'Date';
  iso: string;
}

interface Pointer {
  __type: 'Pointer';
  className: string;
  objectId: string;
}

interface ParseObject {
  __type: 'Object';
  className: string;
}

type ParseAttributes<T> = JsonToAttributeTypes<JsonToAttributeTypes<T, Pointer, ParseObject>, DateJson, Date>

type JsonToAttributeTypes<T, S, R> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends S
  ? R
  : T[k] extends S | null
  ? R | null
  : T[k] extends S | undefined
  ? R | undefined
  : T[k] extends S | null | undefined
  ? R | null | undefined
  : T[k] extends Record<string, unknown> ? JsonToAttributeTypes<T[k], S, R> : T[k]
```

##### Input

This input covers most of the edge cases

```js
type Test = {
  user: Pointer;
  employee?: {
    pointer?: Pointer | null;
    name: string;
    company: string;
  };
  date?: DateJson;
  other: {
    date: DateJson | null;
    testKey: number;
  };
  nested: {
    date: DateJson;
    deep: {
     pointer: Pointer | null
     another: {
       test?: string;
       date?: DateJson | null
     }
   }
  }
}
```

##### Output

This is the expected output. keeping only want to change one type to another recursively (mostly 3 to 4 levels). There could be more types that needs to be converted

```js
 {
  user: ParseObject;
  employee?: {
    pointer?: ParseObject | null;
    name: string;
    company: string;
  };
  date?: Date;
  other: {
    date: Date | null;
    testKey: number;
  };
  nested: {
    date: Date;
    deep: {
     pointer: ParseObject | null
     another: {
       test?: string;
       date?: Date | null
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Also, is it possible to rewrite `JsonToAttributeTypes<JsonToAttributeTypes<T, Pointer, ParseObject>, DateJson, Date>` with array of types and loop?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMRLlW) meet your needs?  It's hard to tell because your example code isn't a [mcve] (there are undeclared types like `Pointer`, `Parse`, and `DateJson`).  It would be very helpful if you could give examples of input/output types, especially potential edge cases.  Anyway, if you can post an example and the above code works for your use cases, I'll write up an answer explaining it.   Otherwise, let me know what's not working.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the answer. Yes that example seems to cover all of my edge cases. I've updated question to include missing details.
Could you please provide some explanation?

Comment: tsc complains if we use `object` as type

Comment: "tsc complains if we use `object` as type" Are you sure it's tsc and not a linter? I don't know what to say about linters other than `extends object` is perfectly valid code and, assuming we're talking about ESLint's ban-types, [I wish that rule would change or at least explain itself better](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640). If you want to change `object` to `Record<string, unknown>` in your code and it works for you that's fine, but I won't do so in my answer since it's not TypeScript that has a problem with it. I'll write up an answer today if I can.

Comment: Yes, it was linter not typescript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking about the `T | null | undefined` cases as separate from the `T | null`, `T | undefined`, and plain `T` cases, let's generalize what you're looking for: you would like `JsonToAttributeTypes<T, S, R>` to replace `S` with `R` in `T` if `S` appears in `T` as any member of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  So if `S` becomes `R`, then `S | 123` should become `R | 123`.  And you also want to recursively replace `S` with `R` in any keys or subkeys of `T`, if `T` is an object type.

Here's one way of writing that:

```
type JsonToAttributeTypes<T, S, R> =
    T extends S ? R : 
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: JsonToAttributeTypes<T[K], S, R> } : 
    T;
```

The `T extends S ? R : ...` type is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which automatically distributes the replacement of `S` with `R` across unions in `T`.

If any union member of `T` is not `S`, then we check to see if it is a non-primitive type (`T extends object`, using [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) which may or may not be a problem for your linter, even though I [don't think it should be a problem](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640)).  If it's non-primitive, we recurse down into it and perform `JsonToAttributeTypes` on each property.  Otherwise, we return the union member of `T` unchanged.

---

We can test it with an example: replace `string` with `boolean` in some object type:

```
type X = JsonToAttributeTypes<
    { a?: string, b: { c: string | number }, c?: { d: string } },
    string,
    boolean
>
/* type X = {
    a?: boolean | undefined;
    b: {
        c: number | boolean;
    };
    c?: {
        d: boolean;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good.  And you can verify that your example also behaves as desired.

---

Of course, for any definition of `JsonToAttributeTypes<T, S, R>`, there are likely to be edge or corner cases where the desired output does not match the actual output.  The current definition might not do what you want if `T` is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) including `S` (so `S & X` will probably not become `R & X`), or if `T` is a function type, etc.  One could possibly tweak the definition to account for or partially account for some of these, but the point is that the only way to be sure that it does what you want is to test extensively against a wide range of potential use cases.  Be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYBUEEFjAE4EsBGArsBCuBHADwoA0UAynQEoB8UAvAFBQ9QpQQAHiSQATOAygB+KEygAuPgOEQxEhPgBWEAMbBpUAN5QA2gGkouJFADWEEAgBmfALqL4yNJhwFipclQo5i50jLJsAL4KfADcnJygkFAAGhywiKgYWHhEJGSQVNy8xgCGUopwPkgA5nT4isY6FVXVUAA+UEiEALb4ENhQEXQ65UZQos14NYODNEU8lVO181D4CAgANhAlSJwsnAD0AFRQidCp7EYrZYprm9vWHYRiEI5WEKJxvKsNK99NnR6fQGHTuWx2X14EUhPBGv2+3wmq3W4KQMJmTxebyQHziUSOB3iCXIUAAIiUSB5rJdDCsAPp0s6KADk5JIzPRuEQkys1Tx8SsJGwjhKOmgAAUEIL+ldvgymVBmZLpdgOSsdBsSnA4AA5ErdCA8mrojTaPQASSRi15-M4KpFYqg4pK2DgEAA8lpdPpaXLGeQWZ6zcA1f9Ndq9QajXzOBF4mcnS63d4cn5AmxLlSvNlfHkApQs1kfLl-AVqHRlUghRWkx6vXoWHQ2RAqU2KRB9sSkigKPoaStCG7sIpK0L0RBumANggQBAIKNfQieGApVX+qNRzKOl0Nht0d8kPrDVBrca-rwdAhJzsQNH0dCVqJ26Nm1STcAABb9eFL8btxSvhk7SAru+68CQlRmPYihdL0-T3uiOKVB8P5Lk+JAAe2b7njwohzmAqG-suq5CiOJFbiBGw4QiOwIJ+36ykRv4QcAoynjGTG-uh86YZSQHboQu7Ud8cZEaJUKxvGJIAKKCJAegfO6xBgMQaSLjwg4Mc6rp1sG46TtOs48YxS4riqG61kG3rATue7UYeUYni0YGwleYA3neKwPoiz68RA75fsOJkItxfk2YJdlESxUG3oCcHYAhKxISQSLqSF-5ku2LnjPhhFEWZa5BdpbpWXo4VCZxPC0fRQVpZVpy9mxznCVxvmZSQ5VUfV4lLj1gyxnEXbQOgeiECUGxKcAKl9omOkprmFDUL2LCDccpwkiNwBjRNymqf23yabV1HygGiqlSG2UalqupHp5In6VOM5zgu1EFUKL31SdkCBvWF0tbC4Y3Y57HZVEAm7sBzx4diuL2bdTlLJdbkeQjNpeZDWLvJ8j5tc2GPQ1jAUMXVvChe10Dg5FzG9jFMFAvBXmIb2KHBd8AB0HOJfihJDVAACyxDbRsICySI4jUMoYsSAAqnQ0uS6o4hQAAanQytpCgGZQAAblK2MJgAwl+Og2LJ8kpWkAtbeNwui4rVCbdtk3TXQZveopu3AGwBwHFACA2CUIBAA)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. is it possible to rewrite `JsonToAttributeTypes<JsonToAttributeTypes<T, Pointer, ParseObject>, DateJson, Date>` with array of types and loop? 
I may need to call `JsonToAttributesTypes` multiple times for different types

Comment: [It is indeed possible](https://tsplay.dev/mLROkw), but that's out of scope for the question.